# using scipy kdtree to find the indexes of nearest values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, kdtree

I am working with a large 2d masked numpy array and need a way to find the indices of the closest masked point for a given pair of indices that correspond to an unmasked point. Since my array is very large it is isn't practical for me to compute the distances to all of the values within my array so I am trying to use a scipy kdtree, however when I query the kdtree the values I get are incorrect.

This lightweight example illustrates my problem:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import numpy as np
#build a small test array
test=[]
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        test.append(i+j)
test=np.array(test)
test=test.reshape((10,10))
test
```

which yields a test array:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])
```

I assume that I am given indices 6,9 (in this case test[6,9] is equal to 15) and I want to find the nearest i,j pair where test[i,j]=16

```
#generate an array of indexes where test is >= 16
greaterThanIndexes=np.where(test>=16)
greaterThanIndexes=np.stack((greaterThanIndexes[0],greaterThanIndexes[1]),axis=1)
greaterThanIndexes
```

which yields the  indices where this condition is satisfied:

```
array([[7, 9],
       [8, 8],
       [8, 9],
       [9, 7],
       [9, 8],
       [9, 9]])
```

I use these indices to populate and query a kdtree:

```
#build a kdtree using these coordinates
LookUpTree=cKDTree(data=greaterThanIndexes)
#find nearest indice when i=2,j=5,should be 8,8
print(repr(LookUpTree.query([2,5])))
#find nearest indices when i=6,j=9, should yield either (7,9) or (8,8)
print(repr(LookUpTree.query([6,9])))
```

which returns (1.0, 0), when I was expecting either (7,9) or (8,8). I have tried this for a number of point pairs none of which has worked as expected. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me why this approach isn't working.

Comment: Your approach is working, see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy-spatial-kdtree-query) the returns are an array of the distances to the nearest neighbour and the index of the nearest neighbour. Try ```LookUpTree.data[LookUpTree.query([6, 9])[-1]]``` to get what you want

Comment: Thank You Nin17, you are right, I just missread that somehow!